# Angular Singleton Service creates multiple new instances despite root injection & single providers declaration

Tags: angular, service, singleton, angular-services

I'm trying to create a service that holds variables that my Angular web app shares across components (components that can read and write to those variables). Because of this, I need it to be a singleton service, but I'm having no luck, as a new instance is created with each new component.

The Service (GlobalService) is declared as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class GlobalService {

  currentUser: string = null;
  currentProject: string = null;
  currentProjectName: string = null;
  canEditInProject: boolean = null;

  constructor() {
    console.log('in global service constructor');
  }
```

with getter and setter methods defined after.

In app.module.ts I have the following:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    LayoutModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [GlobalService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

where it is declared in providers. I've searched my project and there are no other provider statements with the service.

Each component that uses it (1) has an import statement up top and then (2) declares a private variable in it's constructor, ex:

```
constructor(private globalService: GlobalService)
```

and uses the this.globalService variable to get or set the service variables.

Nonetheless, with each new page load, I see from my print statement in global.service.ts that the constructor is called, and a new instance is created. Then of course, all my variables are null and nothing persists.

Any idea what's going wrong? Or any other solution ideas? I tried using localStorage and sessionStorage before, but had some instability there as well.... I'm stumped

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you have put:

`
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
`

You don't need to put your GlobalService in providers anymore. Have you by any chance tried that?

Comment: I just tried, but no luck. Any idea if It's possible my entire app instance is restarting with certain component calls?

Comment: How do you navigate to your other Components, because RouterModule.forRoot([]) is empty?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Angular, so I can't be sure, but I have a separate layout-routing.module that has @NgModule({
  declarations: [],

  imports: [
    FontAwesomeModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],

  exports: [RouterModule]
})

along with all of the routes defined above it. And then each component has its own module + routing module.

Happy to provide more detail in an edit if you think that may be the cause

Comment: As long as you just use one RouterModule.forRoot([]) everything should be fine.

Comment: yep, only the one in app.module

Comment: Each time you use [provider], you create a new instance. NOTE: IF you use `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` NOT put in any module as provider

Comment: My understanding was that it was necessary in app.module.ts. Is that not the case??

Comment: If you have already put `{ providedIn: 'root }` you don't need to provide it any modules anymore since it will be made as a singleton and provided automatically once it's referenced

Comment: I see, thanks! Still have the same issue of the app restarting, but I'll assume it's a separate problem

Comment: @coleen I know this is pretty old thread, but just wanted to know were you able to resolve it finally ?At the moment I too run into the same issue with Angular 16